# Finding coefficients where part of the coefficient may appear in the terms

Tags: factorization, coefficients

A minimal example is given below. My goal is that given a algebraic expression such as:

```
expr = a^2 + a b + a^3 b + 2 a^2 b^2 + a b^3
```

I'm trying to find a command, that I will call `CoefficientFactor` that can take an expression and argument and factor out that argument wherever possible to the highest order. For example:

```
CoefficientFactor[expr, (a+b)]
> a (a + b) + a b (a + b)^2
```

Where essentially `a+b` are acting as if they were powers of `x`:

$$      a (a + b) + a b (a + b)^2 \iff      a x + (a b) x^2$$

As far as I can tell the functions; `Factor`, `Coefficient`, `CoefficientList`. Do not quite acheive this goal.

Sorry if this is a minor oversight on my part.

Comment: As well, I'm very new to mathematica. So for context (in case this is a silly way to even try and solve my problem), what I would ultimately like to do is have a rule where I substitute `(a+b) -> c` for instance. This substitution does not work on the initial form but would work on the desired form.

Comment: Sometimes, but not always, `Simplify[expression,a+b==q]` where `a` and `b` but not `q` appear in expression and `q` is simpler than `a+b` then `Simplify` will spend a fair amount of effort trying to rearrange the expression into `a+b` parts then it will replace those `a+b` with `q`. It isn't perfect. Sometimes it will go down one path and get stuck and not complete all of the process. But you can try that on some of your examples and see how well it works. Then you can replace `q` with `a+b` and hope it doesn't undo what it has accomplished. Tell us how well it worked

Comment: Taking a hint from @Bill, one thing that works on your expression is `Collect[Simplify[expr, a + b == q], q, Factor] /. q -> a + b`. Provided that the result of the `Simpify` operation yields something nice, `Collect`ing on `q` and then replacing `q` with `a+b` yields a nice expression. It's worth trying on a couple of use cases and seeing if it generally gives you what you need.  The examples where such a thing breaks down might give us hints as to how to make this more robust.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there are multiple possible outputs that might be "nice". Do you have an actual figure of merit or algorithm that explains how you want the final expression to look? If you had those parameters, it'd be easier to answer this question. For instance, I could imagine doing a replacement like $a+b \to s$, $a-b\to d$, collecting on $s$ and plugging the others back in. However, this would lead to a different final expression which is "nice" but isn't the same.

Comment: For instance, consider `Collect[expr /. d -> a - b, s, Simplify] /. s -> a + b`. The final expression isn't as compact, but it's "nice" from a particular point of view.  If "nice" just means as compact as possible, then I think my version of Bill's suggestion might be the best thing. Otherwise, do you think there's a way that you could specify more precisely what the desired end expression is?

Comment: @Bill thank you! Your suggestion combined with @march continuation got the equation exactly to form. It also worked on the actual equation I was considering which has a much more intimidating look and it still handled it flawlessly. I added an extra line to try and better demonstrate the form I was trying to achieve. Basically, in my actual equation, the problem can be parameterized later in terms of `(a+b)` and so I wanted to have the form of a polynomial of this future coordinate.

Comment: If either of you wanted to repost your comment as an answer I would obviously accept it but if this question is ultimately too trivial I can also close it :)

Comment: `(((expr /. {a -> x-b} // Factor) /. b-x -> -a) // Expand) /. x -> a+b` works but may not do what you want in general.

Comment: There can be different results, all equivalent, depending on what is allowed. Here is one such. `In[586]:= expr = a^2 + a b + a^3 b + 2 a^2 b^2 + a b^3;
replacementpoly = (a + b) - t;
PolynomialReduce[expr, replacementpoly, {a, b, t}][[2]] /. t -> (a + b)

Out[588]= -b (a + b) + (a + b)^2 - b^2 (a + b)^2 + b (a + b)^3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simple code, while not checked for robustness, works on the OP's examples:

```
expr = a^2 + a b + a^3 b + 2 a^2 b^2 + a b^3;
Collect[Simplify[expr, a + b == q], q, Factor] /. q -> a + b
(* a (a + b) + a b (a + b)^2 *)
```

This combines the insight by Bill in a comment to the OP with the use of one of my most-used (when doing symbolic algebraic manipulations) *Mathematica* functions `Collect`.

---

An alternative version of this removes all instances of `a` and replaces the with `a - b`, which might better under some circumstances:

```
Collect[expr /. a -> aPb - b, aPb] /. aPb -> a - b
(* -(a - b) b + (a - b)^3 b + (a - b)^2 (1 - b^2) *)
```

This is also a "nice" simplified expression, and might be more useful in certain contexts.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem of coding, but a problem of computation. Please try the following code:

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_] := Module[{tmp1, z},
    tmp1 = CoefficientList[PolynomialReduce[x1, {x2 - z}, x3][[-1]], z];
    MapThread[#1*x2^#2 &, {tmp1, Range[0, Length[tmp1] - 1]}] // Total
   ]

tmp1 = f[exp, a + b, {a, b}]
(* -(b*(a + b)) + b*(a + b)^3 + (a + b)^2*(1 - b^2) *)

tmp1 - exp // Simplify
(* 0 *)
```